# File upload validation of the whole batch of selected file

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

In fine uploader the file upload validation works on each file basis . I would like to validate the whole batch of selected file. suppose i have selected 10 files the size of the whole batch is 10mb and i have a limit of uploding maximum of 5mb.

Is there any way to get the total size of flies selected. I want to do it in Html5 compatable browsers and as well as Html4 browsers ie IE.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far in an attempt to resolve this problem. Also, what language(s) will this project be done in?

Comment: This is a html file upload plugin written in javascript .

Comment: Commenters: please look at the tags before commenting.  This is a question for the fine-Uploader library.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no way to do this in IE9 or older, as File API support is required (and not present in IE9 and older).  Without File API support, there is absolutely no way to determine file size client-side.

That said, I can provide a solution for you in all other browsers.  The key to this is use of the `onValidateBatch` [callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html).  For example:

```
var maxAllowedBatchSize = 5000000;

$('#uploadContainer').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: '/my/endpoint'
    }
)}
    .on('validateBatch', function(event, fileOrBlobDataArray) {
        var totalSize = 0;

        $.each(fileOrBlobDataArray, function(idx, fileOrBlobData) {
            totalSize += fileOrBlobData.size;
        });

        // Tell Fine Uploader to ignore the entire batch of files
        // if the batch exceeds the total size limit.
        if (totalSize > maxAllowedBatchSize) {
            return false;     
        } 
    });
```

You will also want to include server-side verification, as client-side checks such as this can be manipulated by users (and will not work in non-File API browsers).

Comment: Thanks Ray for the solution. I am implementing the code as following

Comment: Thanks Ray for the solution I am not getting a callback what could be wrong
manualuploader.on('validatebatch', function(fileOrBlobDataArray) {
                   // alert('hi');
                    var totalSize = 0;

                    qq.each(fileOrBlobDataArray, function(idx, fileOrBlobData) {
                        totalSize += fileOrBlobData.size;
                    });


                    // if the batch exceeds the total size limit.
                    if (totalSize > maxAllowedBatchSize) {
                        return false;
                    }

                });

Comment: The case is important for the event names.  The event name is 'validateBatch', not 'validatebatch'.  Also, the first parameter passed to all event handlers when using the jQuery plug-in is "event".  Are you using jQuery?  Let me know and I will update my answer and the question tags accordingly.

Comment: Yes Ray i am using jquery.